# new file column per line count

Tags: file, count, line, spaces

I ran into a problem importing 2 out of 4 files into a program from another.

I get ERROR:

> A line in the STAR file contains fewer columns than the number of
>   labels. Expected = 17 Found = 1

When I do this on a file I see 1 for every line:

```
awk -F',' '{print NF}'
```

When I do this I see 17:

```
awk '{ FS = " " } ; { print NF}'
```

How can I create a new file with that is read as 17 columns?